# Standard way for Eclipse plugins to run code in a new jvm?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm working on an Eclipse plugin (a builder) and I'd like to use a library that isn't threadsafe.  Of course, I'd like to run code from that library in parallel.  Is there a standard way for an Eclipse plugin to run code in a new sub-jvm (cross-platform; I don't want to maintain windows/mac/linux/... versions)?  I'm perfectly happy to say that the memory requirements for this feature will be large (multiple gig is fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a private launch configuration.  We do this extensively in Grails-IDE.  I'd recommend that you have a look at the source code.  Our infrastructure may be more than you need, but it can get you the idea.

You just create a launch configuration for the external process and launch it.  A good place to look at what we do is here:

https://github.com/SpringSource/grails-ide/blob/master/org.grails.ide.eclipse.core/src/org/grails/ide/eclipse/commands/GrailsExecutor.java

The `syncExec()` method gets a launch configuration for a particular grails command and a particular project, then it customizes it for system processes and listeners.  Finally, then command is launched, synchronously.  This works fairly well for us.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.  At first glace it seems like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a library that is not thread safe, then you need to ensure that the library is used with proper synchronization to avoid any problems. One way, that might suit you, is that you ensure that all utilization of that library happens in a single thread. Another approach which might be more tedious in your case is that all methods that utilize the library are synchronized. In cases similar to yours I have always preferred the former.

You can create a special thread that would be responsible for all operations that need your library. Depending on your need you can either have all calls asynchronous or synchronous, but you will need to implement some kind of call-back mechanism to get results. A convenient way to achieve this is to use the [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) interface. Implement an executor that will ensure that all tasks are run within within the same thread in the order they were pushed to the executor. The docs for `Executor` have a nice example to give you a start. You can add additional methods to that example to have a synchronous execute, and even an execute method that returns results synchronously. For this you can have a look at the [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface as well.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question - @AndrewEisenberg's answer is the sort of answer I was looking for.  I really do need to execute calls to the library in parallel; since I can't make the library threadsafe, I need to run it in completely different jvms.  (Calls to the library take tens of seconds, so adding synchronization on my side isn't useful).

Comment: No problem... I just didn't realize that parallel calls were as important, in which case there are other ways to ensure thread safety. A single thread serial executor being on of them. But since parallel calls are important for you so I agree with you on your choice.